# Есть два отрезка, общей длинной 45м.Один короче другого на одну пятую. Какая длинна каждого из отрезков?

Tags: python-3.x

Помогите решить с помощью Python.
Пытался посчитать на пальцах:

```
total_l = 45
part = 45 // 5
part_1 = (total_l - part) // 2
part_2 = part_1 + part
print(part_1)
print(part_2)
```

получилось 18 и 27
ОТВЕТ НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ.((

Comment: На самом деле задание неоднозначно, потому что неочевидно от какого из отрезков считается 1/5. Один очевидный ответ `20 + 25`. Второй, `20.(45) + 24.(54)` (в скобках период).

Comment: В любом случае это задание для школьника 5 класса, а не для программирования на питоне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша задача - решение обычной системы из 2х переменных:

```
x + y   = 45
y + x/5 = x
```

```
x           = 45 - y
y + 9 - y/5 = 45 - y
```

```
x           = 45 - y
5y + 45 - y = 45*5 - 5y
```

```
x  = 45 - y
9y = 45*4
```

```
x = 25
y = 20
```

---

Для более обобщённого случая

```
x + y   = z
y + x/5 = x
```

решением является

```
x = 4z/9
y = 5z/9
```

Comment: В домножении на 5 в самом конце потеряна пятёрка. Должно быть `5y + 45 - y = 45 * 5 - 5y`

Comment: @AlexeyTen точно, сейчас исправлю, спасибо

Comment: И пишите ответ текстом, а не картинкой